# Remove dependency to logging code

Tags: c#, .net, oop, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I have more like desing question as I'm refactoring quite big piece of code that I took over.

It's not modular, basically it's pseudo-object-oriented code. It contains hard coded dependencies, no interfaces, multiple responsibilities etc. Just **mayhem**.

Among others it contains a great deal of internal calls to class called **Audit**, that contains methods like **Log, Info, LogError** etc... That class has to be configured in application config in order to work, otherwise it's crash. And that's the main pain for me. And please, let's focus on that issue in responses, namely **making client code independent of logging classes/solutions/frameworks**.

And now, I would like those classes, that have that **Audit** class dependency hardcoded, refactored in order to obtain several benefits:

1. First is to extract them nicely to different assemblies, as I will need some functionality available in other applications (for instance generating attachments code - let's call it **AttachmentsGenerator** class, that until now was specyfic to one application, but now that code could be used in many places)
2. Remove internal dependencies so that other application that will take advantage of my **AttachmentsGenerator** class without the need to add reference to other
3. Do a magic trick in order to allow **AttachmentsGenerator** class to report some audit info, traces etc. But I don't want it to have hardcoded implementation. As a matter of fact, I don't want it to be mandatory, so it would be possible to use **AttachmentsGenerator** without that internal logging configured and without the necessity for the client code to add reference to another assemblies in order to use logging. Bottom line: if client code wants to use **AttachmentsGenerator**, it adds reference to assembly that contains that class, then it uses **new** operator and that's all.

What kind approach can I use in terms of design patterns etc to achieve it? I would appreciate some links to articles that address that issue - as it can be timeconsuming to elaborate ideas in answer. Or if you can suggest simple interface/class/assembly sketch.

Thanks a lot, 
Paweł

Edit 1: As my question is not quite clear, I'll rephrase it once again: **This is my plan, are there other interesting ways to do this?**

Comment: It sounds like you know exactly how you want to refactor.  Which suggests there is no need for an answer.

Comment: I did something similar before, for instance AttachmentsGenerator can have event Audit, or it can expose setter like LogSing of type ILogSink, which I will implement in my own client assembly if necessary. But I would like to go further and extend my knowledge :) Perhaps some of you struggled with similar issues before, and can provide me with nice articles, blogs etc.

Comment: Yes. I'm just going to repeat the same stuff I did before, so before I start it once again, I want to make sure I'm not brain dead. I'll update question with your question :) Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like the easiest way to do this would be to use dependency injection.

1. Create a generic `ILogger` interface with methods for logging.
2. Create a concrete implementation of `ILogger` that just does nothing for all the methods (e.g. `NullLogger`)
3. Create another concrete implementation that actually does logging via whatever framework you choose (e.g. log4net)
4. Use a DI tool (spring, structure map, etc.) to inject the appropriate implementation depending on whether or not you want logging enabled.

Comment: Thx. Any links to DI .NET tool code listings that exemplify the idea kindly requested :)

Comment: @dragonfly - here's one example using spring: http://forum.springframework.net/showthread.php?t=4792

Answer (score 3):

[Implement logging (and any other cross-cutting concerns) as a Decorator](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/04/07/DependencyInjectionIsLooseCoupling.aspx). That's way more [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29) than having to inject some ILogger interface into each and every service (which would violate both the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)).